# Altitude in tetrahedron

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

I was reading a book there , I saw the below question in the book  .

My doubt is that how they have written length of altitude is same as projection of AD on ABC  ?

Please explain if possible with a diagram
[image: Image]]

Comment: I cannot post the image as not have enough reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope the following picture can clarify ……[image]

Answer (score -1):

The idea is that volume of the tetrahedron equals $1/3$ base $\times$ height.

Or, Height = 3V / Area of the base.

But rather than working with tetrahedra and triangles, the math is a little nicer if we use parallelepeiped and parallelograms.

In which case, Height = Volume / Area.

Translate everything such that $A$ is at the origin.

The volume of the parallelepeiped formed by the vectors $AB, AC, AD$ equals the absolute value of the determinant of the matrix with those vectors as rows.

The area of parallelogram formed by $AB$ and $AC$ equals the absolute value of cross product $AB\times AC$

Comment: How this answers the OP's question

Comment: Can you explain me  more about why we have taken projection.

Comment: $\frac {AB\times AC}{\|AB\times AC\|}$ returns a vector that is perpendicular to the plane containing the points $a,b,c.  AD\cdot \frac {AB\times AC}{\|AB\times AC\|}$ returns the projection onto that vector.  That is the component of $AD$ that is perpendicular to the plane.